# Error in passing variables from one jsp to another jsp page through jsp:include tag

Tags: java, jsp

I have following code in my jsp page

```
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="ref" class="comp_Mps.Comp_Mps_hs"/>
<%
   String s_date= request.getParameter("startdate");
   pageContext.setAttribute("s_date", s_date);
   String e_date= request.getParameter("enddate");
   pageContext.setAttribute("e_date", e_date);
   ref.refarray_vac1(s_date,e_date);
   ref.ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User(s_date,e_date);
   %>

<%
   String ref_name= request.getParameter("ref_logtime");
   pageContext.setAttribute("ref_name", ref_name);
   ref.FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen(ref_name);
   ref.refernece(ref_name);

%>
```

Now I want to pass variables s_date ,e_date and ref_name ingto another jsp page .For this I did code as

```
 <jsp:include page="Comp_Mps_Hs.jsp?ref_logtime=<%=ref_name%>;&startdate=<%=s_date%>;&&enddate=<%=e_date%>"></jsp:include>

I want to pass above said variable sin Comp_Mps_Hs.jsp page.But when I run it ,then I get an error that
```

**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [=] is not a hexadecimal digit

**
How to pass these variables in another jsp?

Comment: seriously dude, this has been mentioned to you before, stop trying to get jsp to do stuff it aint intended for.  Learn a framework like struts or stripes or spring mvc.  trying to maintain a jsp with 3207 lines of code aint going to be fun.

Comment: I seriously suggest you to move your java code to a servlet from JSP, scriptlets are so old and are very hard to maintain :-) You can try using Expression Language in JSP in your include tag like ${ref_name} for accessing any values set in scope by you or directly ${param.startdate} for accessing request parameters of current request

Comment: I have reduced it ,done changes in my code.I just want to know how to pass variables from one jsp to another jsp.

Comment: @Arkantos,how to pass these varibale through jsp:include.

Comment: You can use EL like i mentioned in my previous comment in include tag

Answer (score 1):

I did by using param as

```
<jsp:include page="Comp_Mps_Hs.jsp">
<jsp:param value="startdate" name="s_date"/>
<jsp:param value="enddate" name="e_date"/>
<jsp:param value="ref_logtime" name="ref_name"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this, it's similar as @tiddi rastogi mentioned.

```
<jsp:include page="Comp_Mps_Hs.jsp">   
<jsp:param name="ref_logtime" value="<%=ref_name%>" />
<jsp:param name="startdate" value="<%=s_date%>" />
<jsp:param name="enddate" value="<%=e_date%>" />
</jsp:include>
```